# Custom translator model privacy

Tags: microsoft-translator

We are currently evaluating microsoft translator services to create live translations for a customer providing us with a dictionary of jargon used in its very specific industry. It is our understanding that this is a job for the [Custom Translator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/customization/).

One of the requirements though is that these special vocabs are not to be fed into publicly available translation models and should stay withing the companies confines.

My question is, when training this Custom Translator, is the training data fed into some public microsoft translation model or is the Custom Translator private? Or asked differently, after having trained the custom translator, can we restrict access to it for a specific domain of users?

---

**Edit:**

On further research we found a paragraph on: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/office/#privacy
stating

> Your IT department also has the ability to partially or completely control translation features. For example, controls can enable or disable a feature, add company-level language models, control permissible language, etc. Learn more about [Microsoft Translator privacy](http://aka.ms/TranslatorPrivacy)

Whereas the Microsoft Translator Privacy clause includes:

> ... We use this data to provide Translator, personalize your experiences, ***and improve our products***...

Does this include enhancing microsofts own translator using Custom Translators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft does not have access to your training data. Custom Translator is an Azure service and is covered by the guarantees of Microsoft’s Online Services Terms. You may share the training material in your workspace with others by inviting them into your workspace. The sharing stops as soon as you remove the invited user from your workspace.
Once you trained a model it is accessible via the Translator API using a category ID. The category ID is a GUID with some additional characters added to it, including a standard category descriptor and a string you may provide. You may choose to share the category ID with others, or keep it secret. Microsoft will not share the category ID. Even if you share the category ID of a trained model, the people who you share with will perform translations under their own account, and won’t be able to extract the original training data from your trained model.